# How to check fields that are not changed or not in record using MongoDB?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query

I tried to update the data in mongodb and without mondification send data using put method .its successfully throw update sucessfully message.but I have doubt how its throw sucess message.

**User Collection**

```
{
        "user_full_name": "lenovo",
        "user_email": "user@techardors.com",
        "user_phone": "9999999999"
}
```

**So I tried to update data without modification using put method**

**put Method **

```
{
        "user_full_name": "lenovo",
        "user_email": "user@techardors.com",
        "user_phone": "9999999999"
}
```

**Expected Output**

```
{
    "n": 0,
    "nModified": 1,
    "ok": 1
}
```

**I got output**

```
{
    "n": 1,
    "nModified": 1,
    "ok": 1
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's understand first result:

1. `n` is the number of matched documents.
2. `nModified` is the number of modified documents.
3. `ok` is the success of query.

> As per your expected result, `n` would be 0 that means no document is matched then `nModified` will also be 0 always.

What you can do is find the document and compare object, If the object is mismatched you can go ahead for update otherwise just return the document.

I would like to share code with you if you have provided sample code for PUT method.

Hope this help!